# Configure spring cloud config uri in a kubernetes cluster

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, minikube, spring-cloud-config

I'm deploying my config server and application which uses it to initalize properties.
The following problem I encounter now is the URI to specify where the config-server is located.

Before it was easy like this:

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:https://localhost:8888/
```

Now in the cluster I try to specify it like this

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:centralconfig-service:8888/
```

This the service name of the config-server (deployment name is 'centralconfig').
Whenever I try this URL i get an Invalid Url exception.

```
Invalid URL: centralconfig-service:8888/
```

I've set up an internal network so they should be able to communicate with eachother.

Anyone knows how to specify the correct URI in the kubernetes-environment?

centralconfig-deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: central-config
  labels:
    app: central-config
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: central-config
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: central-config  
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - name: central-config
          image: "central-config:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports: 
            - containerPort: 8888
          resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes: null
status: {}
```

centralconfig.service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: central-config
  labels:
    app: central-config
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels: 
      app: central-config
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: central-config  
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - name: central-config
          image: "central-config:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports: 
            - containerPort: 8888
          resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes: null
status: {}
```

endpoints:
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean with you "have setup an internal network" have you exposed your centralconfig with a service? if so can you show us the service definition and the output of kubectl get endpoints?

Comment: Please show the YAML of your service and deployment.

Comment: Provided the yaml files

Comment: the service and deployment yaml are identical, copy-paste error or did you forget to create a service? see the answer below for a possible solution, btw

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that missing the "http://" or "https://" prefix is the actual cause of the problem.

So give this one a try:

```
spring.config.import=optional:configserver:https://centralconfig-service:8888/
```